# Unable to connect to a Subversion repository at disk URL file:///

Tags: svn, pycharm

> Note: I am aware that there are SIMILAR questions. But none appear to
>   solve issue of wanting to use "file:" without svnserver.

I am trying to use Subversion in PyCharm. I have been able to create a repository (or at least it appears in the list). But when I try to import a folder I get:

[image]

[image]

Actually it is on H: drive BUT I get exact same error:

Answer (score 0):

H:\RepositoriesPython is not a Subversion repository. It appears to be an empty directory. So the error that you receive is expected.

Run the `svnadmin create C:\RepositoriesPython` command to create a repository at this location.

Comment: No, my Repository is actually called "RepositoriesPython"

Comment: Run `dir C:\RepositoriesPython` and show the result in your question post.

Comment: I have done that. It is actually on the h: drive, but I get the exact same error

Comment: H:\RepositoriesPython is not a repository and it appears to be an empty directory. I do not understand what you expect. Do you confuse a working copy with repository maybe?

Comment: I am new to Pycharm. I was hoping to put a new Project into Subversion. In c#, I would "Add solution to Subversion". I assume the equivalent in PyCharm is to "Import directory"? Is this not the case? I have a project "tester2019" and I created and empty folder RepositoriesPython.

Comment: OK I did that. So is the first thing I do "Import directory"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188213/discussion-between-maninmoon-and-bahrep).

Comment: I import directory, but that was thousands of files - is that correct?